# Consulta como dirigirse al fragment de los datos

Tags: android-studio

esperando que todos se encuentren muy bie, tengo una duda, antes de grabar verifico que los edittext que son obligatorios de ingresar datos, si están vacíos pretendo que se dirija al fragment de origen en este caso asegurado y al de licencia por ejemplo, poseo el siguiente código:

```
else if (licencia.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo la Licencia del Conductor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        Asegurado fragment = (Asegurado) fm.findFragmentById("asegurado");
        
        return;
    }
```

lo que paso que tanto la variable Asegurado y asegurado que es el nombre del fragment, me da errores, aunque las tenga inicializada en fragment de datos, y lo otro que hice anteriormente es Asegurado.txtlicencia.requestfocus(); no me daba error, pero al momento de ejecutarla con el debug realiza un loop, favor de asesorme como lo puedo hacer y desde ya muchas gracias.

he cambiado un poco el código, ahora lo tengo así:

```
private asegurado mFragmentAsegurado;
```

en el infalter del fragment llamado datos:

```
mFragmentAsegurado = (asegurado) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("asegurado");
```

y por último en la el private antes de grabar:

```
else if (licencia.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo la Licencia del Conductor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (mFragmentAsegurado != null) {
            mFragmentAsegurado.txtlicencia.requestFocus();
        }
        return;
    }
```

no me da error en el logcat, y al hacerlo en el debug me dive que mFargmentAsegurado = null, no cae la app, pero no hace lo que pretendo es que se valla al fragment por ejemplo del asegurado, favor de ayudarme.

nuevo código:

```
else if (licencia.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo la Licencia del Conductor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        fragmentAsegurado = new asegurado();
        fragmentAsegurado = (asegurado) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("asegurado");
        if (fragmentAsegurado != null) {
            fragmentAsegurado.txtlicencia.requestFocus();
        }
        return;
    }
```

este es el error que me envía:

```
Process: com.example.prueba, PID: 28125
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0801ba (com.example.prueba:id/segundo) for fragment asegurado{c883369} (9663caf1-4547-4490-87f9-1f80e224089e id=0x7f0801ba tag=asegurado)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:514)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1901)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1819)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1762)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2987)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2890)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3129)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:552)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1901)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1819)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1731)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:323)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:249)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27129)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7980)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27129)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7980)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:197)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:145)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27129)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7980)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:496)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27129)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7980)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:197)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27129)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7980)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27129)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7980)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:197)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:1278)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27129)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:4536)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:3228)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3533)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2919)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:10491)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1108)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:866)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:797)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1092)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 28125 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:60579', transport: 'socket'
```

y es el nuevo código que utilizo en el inflater:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_datos, container, false);
    fragmentAsegurado = new asegurado();
    //fragmentAsegurado = (asegurado) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Tercero");

    //fragmentAsegurado = new asegurado();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.segundo, fragmentAsegurado, "asegurado").commit();
```

Comment: Hola Hector, importante agregar el mensaje de los errores que se muestran, saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys master ahí te hice lo que pediste, edite de  nuevo el código y no puedo solucionarlo.

Comment: @Jorgesys hola te cuento como te mencione anteriormente en el logcat no me  muestra el error, ya que no se cae la aplicación, y en edebug me indica que el fragmentAsegurado = null, por eso no puedo dirigirme a dicho fragmento. arriba te dejo el nuevo código: